# Strange things at the begining of the data of TCP Packet

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sockets, tcp

When I send a packet:

```
var m = new Object();
m.a=action;
m.p=payload;
m = JSON.stringify(m)
m = m.replace(/\s+/g, '')
console.log("SEND TO POD: \n" + m)
outbound.write(m)
```

The value of m is for example:

> {"a":5,"p":{"to":"234","ms":"5435","md":"23","sc":"23"}}

But I receive that with 3 strange characters at the beginning of the data in the packet

> �5

This is the data from wireshark(hex + ascii):

My first true char '{' is the 7B

```
e8 07 35 00
0030   00 00 7b 22 61 22 3a 35 2c 22 70 22 3a 7b 22 74
0040   6f 22 3a 22 32 33 22 2c 22 6d 73 22 3a 22 32 33
0050   22 2c 22 6d 64 22 3a 22 32 33 22 2c 22 73 63 22
0060   3a 22 32 33 22 7d 7d
```

Any idea? Could it be the library I am using?

I would like to solve this without cleaning this from the receptor(send the packet well)

My library: npm json-tcp-socket (https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-tcp-socket)

Thanks

Comment: What library are you using? And isn’t there also three zeroes so six bytes? Of which the last four look like length.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forget to say the library. My first char is the first 7B('{'), when I receive this on the server only appear 3 strange char at the begining